# Copy emails into hard-drive folder

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to VBA out of Outlook every individual email I have in Outlook to a folder on my hard-drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MailItem.SaveAs. It supports several formats - olTxt, olMsg, olHTML, etc.

Comment: I googled "save outlook as file eml vba" and found this:  http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=5&messageid=31299.  You dig Outlook!  :o)